# Community Builder - Make a drop zone

Tags: customer-community, community-builder

I have a custom lightning component that I want to have a dropzone for other lightning components. For example, I have a custom component and inside that, I want to use the out-of-the-box components of napili template such as buttons. How do I configure it in my custom component? I'll be using it for the drag-and-drop functionality of the community builder

Comment: I don't think it is possible, just curious, what is your use-case? If you want to use out of the box components on a page why do you need a custom component as holder? If it is just for styling there are other possible ways of handling it.

Comment: I have a custom login page (built with components) but I want to use Napili's social login (out of the box) component. Since I am using a custom page, there's no way for me to drag that social login component inside my component. It's either above my component or below it. I wonder if I could add something like how we configure custom templates where in you define {! body } or something like that and it will make that part of the component a dropzone.